# Custom Automated HTML Email

Tags: css, google-apps-script, html-email, google-docs-api

how to send custom html automated email once when google form is submitted? I want to have my company logo on top and a border around the email. Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you got negative points because your question is so broad and apparently you made absolutely no effort to do it yourself. But hey, I feel your pain, because I went through the same.

I am assuming you have already figured out how to send an email with the form submitted data using the on form submit trigger. I am no expert, but a good starting point to get it to send in html would be to design your email with an html/css designer and make it look exactly how you want it, then copy the code as the body variable in your script:

```js
var messageBody = '<html><body style="border:1px solid black"><img src="path-to-logo/logo.jpg" /><h1>Heading</h1><p>You submitted:</p><p>'+[form data]+'.</p></body></html>';
```

And then send the email using `htmlBody` as suggested by eggyal. Worked for me.

Comment: and also have a look at [some html reference site](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/), it has some tutorials and examples as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `htmlBody` advanced argument to [`MailApp.sendEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_mailapp#sendEmail).